# Сортировка опций селекта букмарклетом (JS)

Tags: javascript

Господа помогите с сортировкой опций списка выбора. Они сейчас сортированы по value, а я хотел бы по тексту.
У меня есть список с целой кучей опций, вроде, такого:

```
Опция 1 Самара;
Опция 2 Москва;
Опция 3 Владивосток;
```

Список задаётся со следующими параметрами: 
`<select class="select__control" id="uniq156387453229221002" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option class="select__option" value="381028">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#uniq156387453229221002');
const options = [...select.querySelectorAll('#uniq156387453229221002 option')];

options.sort((a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent));

options.forEach((option) => {
  select.append(option);
});
```

```html
<select class="select__control" id="uniq156387453229221002">
  <option class="select__option" value="1">Самара</option>
  <option class="select__option" value="2">Москва</option>
  <option class="select__option" value="3">Владивосток</option>
</select>
```

Comment: На моей странице не работает ( можем обойтись без выборки по ID? только по классу? (отсортировать все выпадающие списки на странице?

Comment: закинул код страницы на paste.ofcode.org/SH9qaDahp6KbVDHFLdNanC

Comment: На таком коде работает Ваш пример, но, видимо уник меняется каждый раз(

Comment: Разобрался, ТНХ!!

Answer (score 0):

Суровый букмарклет )), с отформатированным в одну строку кодом, для помещения его в href-атрибут ссылки:

```
javascript: var opts = [], sel = "select.select__control"; document.querySelectorAll(sel + " .select__option").forEach(function (el) { opts.push(el); el.remove();}); opts.sort(function (a, b) { var a = a.text, b = b.text; return a.localeCompare(b);}); var selel = document.querySelector(sel); opts.forEach(function (el) { selel.append(el); }); document.querySelector(sel + " option:nth-child(1)").setAttribute("selected", "selected"); void 0;
```

Отформатированный код:

```
var opts = [], sel = "select.select__control"; 
document.querySelectorAll(sel + " .select__option")
.forEach(function (el) {
    opts.push(el);
    el.remove();
});
opts.sort(function (a, b) {
    var a = a.text, b = b.text;
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});
var selel = document.querySelector(sel);
opts.forEach(function (el) {
    selel.append(el);
});
document.querySelector(sel + " option:nth-child(1)").setAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

**Обновлено** : теперь для select-элемента используется селектор `select.select__control`

Comment: На моей странице не работает ( можем обойтись без выборки по ID? только по классу? (отсортировать все выпадающие списки на странице?

Comment: закинул код страницы на https://paste.ofcode.org/SH9qaDahp6KbVDHFLdNanC

Comment: На таком коде работает Ваш пример, но, видимо уник меняется каждый раз(

Comment: Разобрался, ТНХ!!

Comment: @ВячеславЕфимов, изменил ответ